# Removing duplicates based on one column and filtering based on data in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables that store data based on submissions of a form and returns from an API endpoint. I'm trying to write a query to give me all data table A with duplicates removed, while also removing test submissions that are stored in table B. Here are the table structures table structures with irrelevant rows removed:

**Table A**

```
submission_id
email
campaign_id
rep_name
```

**Table B**

```
email
campaign_id
is_test
```

Table B contains a single row per email address with data about that submission.

Table A should contain between 1-4 rows for each email address & campaign_id with different data in rep_name column, however I have duplicate rows in Table A that I would like to remove with the query. ex.

```
    Table A Data
    submission_id    email             campaign_id    rep_name
    1                test@test.com     campaign_1     john smith
    2                test@test.com     campaign_1     mary joe
    3                test@test.com     campaign_1     kevin guy
    4                test@test.com     campaign_1     john smith
    5                test@test.com     campaign_1     mary joe
    6                test@test.com     campaign_1     kevin guy
    7                real@real.com     campaign_1     john smith
    8                real@real.com     campaign_1     mary joe
    9                real@real.com     campaign_1     kevin guy
    10               real@real.com     campaign_1     john smith
    11               real@real.com     campaign_1     mary joe
    12               real@real.com     campaign_1     kevin guy
```

```
    Table B Data
    email             campaign_id    is_test
    test@test.com     campaign_1     Y
    real@real.com     campaign_1     N
    real@real.com     campaign_2     Y
    real@real.com     campaign_2     N
    test@test.com     campaign_2     Y
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
real@real.com     campaign_1     john smith
real@real.com     campaign_1     mary joe
real@real.com     campaign_1     kevin guy
```

Here is my current attempt at the query that is not resulting in duplicates being removed.

`SELECT a.* FROM table_a a LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT email FROM table_b WHERE is_test='N' AND campaign_id='some_campaign_id') as b ON a.email=b.email WHERE a.campaign_id='some_campaign_id';`

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

Something like this:

```
select distinct a.email, a.campaign_id, a.rep_name
from a join
     b
     on a.email = b.email and a.campaign_id = b.campaign_id
where b.is_test = 'N';
```

You can add a filter for the campaign in the `where` clause as well.

Comment: unfortunately distinct does not work. I should have included there is a submission ID that is unique to every row so distinct doesn't work properly on that column

Comment: So update the example data and expected output with that column submission ID @mannr

Comment: Then this query is still valid and should give the correct results.. Because you don't display submission ID within the expected output.. @mannr.. Besides i don't think you need to join really to get the correct results. `select distinct a.email, a.campaign_id, a.rep_name
from a` would also work just fine.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I need to join to remove submissions that are tests from table b